# SML error in printing off length of largest number in a list

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, sml

I'm using 3 functions to find the largest number in a list and print it's length.

Sample input would be maxL [5, 199, 3000, 63];

```
fun max(a,b) = 
if 
    a>b 
then 
    a 
else 
    b;
fun maxL(L) = 
    if L=[] then 
        0
    else
        let 
            val largest = max(hd(L), maxL(tl(L)))
        in
            num_digits largest
        end;

fun num_digits 0 = 0
|num_digits 1 = 1
| num_digits x = num_digits(x div 10) + 1;
```

Sample input/output

```
- maxL [5, 199, 3000, 63];
val it = 1 : int
```

Here I modified the program to just print largest to verify it is finding largest

```
- use "hw4.sml";
[opening hw4.sml]
val num_digits = fn : int -> int
val max_digits = fn : int list -> int
val max = fn : int * int -> int
val maxL = fn : int list -> int
val it = () : unit
- maxL [5, 199, 3000, 63];
val it = 3000 : int
```

Here I'm testing that 3000, or largest, is actually printing off the correct length which it is.

```
- num_digits 3000;
val it = 4 : int
```

My question is: Why does it print off 1 when I call `num_digits largest`, but if I call `num_digits 3000` it prints 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using 3 functions to find the largest number in a list and print its length.

Decompose your goal in simpler steps:

- find the largest number in a list
- and print its length

You may already see that this is not what you are doing. Your algorithm does the following:

- decompose a list in first element and tail list
- get the maximum between said first element and `maxL(tail)`
- compute the digit length of that maximum

If you expand the inner call to `maxL` the difference becomes obvious:

- decompose a list in first element and tail list
- decompose tail list in second element and second tail list
- get the maximum between said second element and `maxL(second tail)`
- compute the digit length of that first maximum
- get the maximum between said first element and *digit length of previous maximum*
- compute the digit length of that maximum

In order to fix the algorithm, you need to pull the call to `num_digits` out of the recursion, and apply it after, as originally stated your goal.

Answer (score 1):

maxL is returning a number of digits but its return value is used as the second argument to max, comparing that value to the value at the head of the list.  Since no number in the list has more than 4 digits, the value of 5 prevails and it has 1 digit.  Hence the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually reduce the expression:

```
   maxL [5, 199, 3000, 63];
=> num_digits (max (5, maxL [199, 3000, 63]))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, maxL [3000, 63]))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, num_digits (max (3000, maxL [63]))))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, num_digits (max (3000, num_digits (max (63, maxL []))))))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, num_digits (max (3000, num_digits (max (63, 0))))))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, num_digits (max (3000, num_digits 63))))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, num_digits (max (3000, 2))))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, num_digits 3000))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits (max (199, 4))))
=> num_digits (max (5, num_digits 199))
=> num_digits (max (5, 3))
=> num_digits 5
   1
```

In short, `maxL` is computing the *number of digits* of a number, not *the greatest number* of a list of numbers, so you can't really use the result produced by `maxL` as an argument to `max`.